# Remove rows of a DataFrame based on a separate vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a vector containing a combination of NA values and strings:

```
v <- c(NA, NA, "text", NA)
```

I also have a separate data frame:

```
df <- data.frame("Col1" = 1:4, "Col2" = 5:8)

Col1   Col2
1      5
2      6
3      7
4      8
```

My goal is to remove the rows of `df` where the corresponding v value is NA. So in this case the output would just be:

```
Col1   Col2
3      7
```

Since the third element of `v` is the only one that's not NA, only the third row of `df` is kept. I tried to accomplish this using a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(v)) {
    if (is.na(v[i])) {
        df <- df[-i, ]
    }
}
```

However, for some reason this just outputs a version of `df` that includes only the 2nd and 4th rows:

```
Col1   Col2
2      6
4      8
```

I can't figure out why the loop isn't working. Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it -

```
df[!is.na(v), ]
```

You don't need a loop. You can always subset any dataframe using a vector of row indices or logical vector (`TRUE` and `FALSE`). `!is.na(v)` generates a logical vector based on `v` and subsets the dataframe accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Just out of curiosity, do you know why my original for loop gave this incorrect output?

Comment: you are removing rows from `df` in the loop so your index `-i` doesn't match up with the modified `df`.